# Trying to write a regex with 4 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am trying to put validation on a textbox onkeypress.
Textbox should contain only 5 digit value and after decimal only upto 4 decimal places. eg,12345 ,12345.2345
.Aspx

```
<input type="number" id='inpSurfIndN' value='' runat="server"  onkeypress="return isFloatNumber(this,event);" />
```

Script

```
<Script>
function isFloatNumber(e, t) {
            var regex = /^[0-9]\d{0,4}(\.\d{1,4})?%?$/
            var regmatch = e.match(regex);
            if (regmatch == null) {
                alert("please fill right value");
                return false;
            }
        }
</Script>
```

i tried but getting not correc output.any idea how to correct it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Try Following**

```js
   $('#inpSurfIndN').keypress(function() {
    this.value = this.value
      .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')           
      .replace(/(^[\d]{4})[\d]/g, '$1')  
      .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')        
      .replace(/(\.[\d]{3})./g, '$1');    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id='inpSurfIndN' value='' runat="server"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = (/^[0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$/);

console.log(regex.test(12345.1234)); // true
console.log(regex.test(12345.12345)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isFloatNumber(val) {
  const num = val.trim();
  const regex = /^\d{5}(\.\d{1,4})?$/;

  return regex.test(num);
}
```

Comment: while this code may answer the question, adding some explanations on why and how it solves the problem would improve the quality of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var regex =  /^\d{5}|(\.\d{1,4})/g
console.log(regex.test('12345')) //true
console.log(regex.test('12345.2')) //true
console.log(regex.test('12345.12345')) //false
console.log(regex.test('12345.1234')) //true
```